# Is there a bug in my IDE - Can't enter values in console using Neatbeans IDE

Tags: java, console

I am unable to input anything from my console after i have run my file.

I am running the following code in main method:

```
   int row1,row2,col1,col2;   
   System.out.println("Enter number of rows and column : ");   
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);   
   row1=sc.nextInt();   
   col1=sc.nextInt();   
   int [][]A=new int [row1][col1];    
   System.out.println("Please enter elements in matrix : ");   
  for(int a = 0; a < row1; a++)    
  {    
     for(int b = 0; b < col1; b++)    
     {    
        A[a][b] = sc.nextInt();    
     }     
  }
```

I have also imported java.util.Scanner prior to running.

There is no error in the import as no error is raised by the IDE while running, I am just unable to enter any value through the console.

Is there any setting or mode i have to configure in my IDE to be able to input values from the console?

I am using Netbeans IDE 12.1 on jdk 15

Comment: When you say "my console" - you need to be using the "Run" window (or "Debug" window if you are debugging). Make sure you click your cursor in the window, first. Then you can type in your integer values (hitting "return" after each entry). If you can't see the "Run" window, then select: Window > Output from the main menus.

Comment: I already click by mouse on console outpot first beore enter input...